# Hibernate. Order only part of list result

Tags: hibernate, hql

Set maxResults for paging and set order by date, but sorting was only for the number(value maxResults) of items, not full list.

```
@Override
public List<News> getNewsList(final List<Integer> rssIds, final int numberOfNewsPerPage, final int indexOfFirstNews) {
    HibernateCallback<List<News>> callback = new HibernateCallback<List<News>>() {

        @Override
        public List<News> doInHibernate(Session sn) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            Query query = sn.createQuery(" from News as n "
                    + "where n.rssId in (:idsParam) "
                    + "order by :orderby");
            query.setParameterList("idsParam", rssIds);
            query.setParameter("orderby", "date desc");
            query.setFirstResult(indexOfFirstNews);
            query.setMaxResults(numberOfNewsPerPage);
            return query.list();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is: "how to only sort the items returned by the query, instead of sorting the whole list, and then applying the first and max results constraints?", then it's not possible without sorting the result list explicitely, in Java, using a Comparator.

The alternative is to use a native SQL query, but the query will depend on which database you're using.